# body_class(); not working with bootstrap navbar fixed top?

Tags: navigation, twitter-bootstrap, body-class

I am trying to use WordPress with a bootstrap template, class `navbar-fixed-top` is conflicting with `body_class();`

Is there a workaround to this problem?

### Edit 1:

Additional details,

I can't see the nav, thet's the main issue. I'm trying to use `<?php body_class(); ?>` to fix this up but no results.

[image: can't see navbar]

Here's the code upto nav:

```
<body id="page-top" <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top affix">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <!-- a lot more code and -->
</body>
```

Here's the body tag from page after rendering:

```
<body id="page-top" class="home blog logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support">
```

Comment: Could you please tell me a bit more in detail exactly what is the conflict?

Comment: Yes, there is more info required in order to help

Comment: worpress's top black nav is covering my website's nav

Comment: Hi, Welcome to WPSE! Unfortunately questions on here must be related to core WordPress development, and your question is about CSS and styling. These types of questions are off-topic here.

Comment: owh! So PHP stuff only?, not even wordpress related frontend questions?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a navwalker to create your bootstrap menu?
Try https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

You can get the fixed-top to add to the menu

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" temscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">    
                        <?php
                            wp_nav_menu( array(
                                'menu'              => 'primary',
                                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                                'depth'             => 2,
                                'container'         => 'div',
                                'container_class'   => '',
                                'container_id'      => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                            );
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the admin-bar and the navbar are overlapping is because they are both fixed to the top of the screen. There are two ways you can deal with this:

With PHP you can remove the admin bar. Add the following to your functions.php or in a standalone plugin:

```
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
```

Or with CSS. Add this to your themes style.css or in the customizer:

```
.admin-bar .navbar { top: 32px; }
```